# Is there minifying Dart scripts in a roadmap?

Tags: compression, dart, minify

I am at the beginning of my adventure with Dart, do please be kind :)

I found some answers related to minifying JS files made from Dart (dart2js), but I cannot find any info about minifying Dart code itself.

Is there any plan to do this?

For JS there are some tools i.e. YUI Compressor.
I think Dart need also such application.

--
Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dart2js](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html) with the `--output-type=dart` to output Dart code instead of JavaScript. Coupled with the `--minify` option you will get a minified dart file.

Comment: @Thomasz Kuter: still it would be nice if a 'generate dart' option was available like the 'generate javascript' one, in the same menu. Maybe you could fill a feature request for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the dart tools page: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html

There are a few things that are perhaps relevant:

```
 --output-type=dart
```

> Output Dart code instead of JavaScript. This option is useful when deploying your app, because it generates a single file
>   containing everything the app needs.

And tree-shaking removes unused code:

> Don’t worry about the size of your app’s included libraries. Thanks to a feature called tree shaking, dart2js omits unused classes, functions, methods, and so on. Just import the libraries you need, and let dart2js get rid of what you don’t need.

Comment: There is no output-type option on the page.

Comment: stop using dart.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if browser can load  snapshot, and never tried. But if so, could fit your needs: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/snapshots/